# How to find the max element from a list of list of float elements?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list of float elements stored in a list. I want to look for the largest element present and do further operations. The list looks like this:

```
tumor_size = [[2.6,3.65],[],[2.0,2.9,1.7,2.5,1.3]]
```

I tried answers from this link: [Python : find max value and index of a list of list of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025499/python-find-max-value-and-index-of-a-list-of-list-of-list)

But it did not help.

To look for the largest element, I use this code:

```
T_stage_list=[]
T_stage = "T2b"
for i in tumor_size:
   for j in i:
   maxlen = max(tumor_size[j])
     if (maxlen>2.0 & maxlen<3.0):
     T_stage = "T2a"
T_stage_list.append(T_stage)
```

This gives me error called "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float"

However, when I try this:

```
ltd =[8.7,5.7]
ltdmax = max(ltd)
```

This successfully gives me 8.7 as a result. So clearly, the float is not the issue. Please help me figure out where I am doing wrong.

Comment: The problem here is in the way you did the double for loop. You're using lists in lists. So at the beginning, ``` for i in tumor_size: ``` sets i as that first list. Then ``` for j in i: ``` sets j to the first entry in that list. So instead of executing ```  max(list) ```  it's actually trying to execute ``` max(2.6) ```

Comment: If you don't mind using `numpy`, try `numpy.hstack(tumor_size).max()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original code, you are iterating over the elements of the sublist and you are using them as indexes, since the element of the sublist is a float, when you use them as an index i.e. you do `tumor_size[2.6]`, hence you get the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float`

Also it should be `and` instead of `&` to chain conditionals together

To fix this, you would need to iterate over the sublists of each list, and calculate the max given that the list is non-empty

```
tumor_size = [[2.6,3.65],[],[2.0,2.9,1.7,2.5,1.3]]

#Find max of each sublist given sublist is non-empty
res = [max(li) for li in tumor_size if li]

print(res)
```

The output will be

```
[3.65, 2.9]
```

Or if we go with your original approach, you can get rid of the inner loop, check for maxlen only if the sublist is non-empty, and do your comparison

```
tumor_size = [[2.6,3.65],[],[2.0,2.9,1.7,2.5,1.3]]


T_stage_list=[]

for i in tumor_size:

    #Default value is T0
    T_stage = "T0"
    #If sublist is non-empty
    if i:
        #Get max and perform comparison
        maxlen = max(i)
        if (maxlen>2.0 and maxlen<3.0):
            T_stage = "T2a"
        else:
            T_stage = "T2b"
    #Add T_stage
    T_stage_list.append(T_stage)

print(T_stage_list)
```

The output will be

```
['T2b', 'T0', 'T2a']
```

Answer (score 3):

Use @Devesh's answer if you want the `max`imum for all sublists, but you can also use:

```
print(list(map(max, filter(None, tumor_size))))
```

`max`imum of the whole list:

```
print(max([x for i in tumor_size for x in i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Each i in:

```
for i in tumor_size
```

is a list.

Each j in:

```
for j in i
```

is a float within that list

so when you use the expression:

```
tumor_size[j]
```

you're using the float j as an index into the `tumor_size` list.

That's what's producing your error.

Answer (score 1):

find max elements in each list:

```
max_elements = [max(l) for l in tumor_size if len(l)>0]
```

then find the max element in the above list:

```
print max(max_elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mx=[max(l) for l in list_name]
mx=max(mx)
```

you can also find the index of the max element:

```
for i in range(len(list_name)):
  if mx==ps[i]:
    print("The digit is "+str(i))
    break
```